# How do I persist graphic data in iPhone/iPad?

Tags: ios, graphics, uiview, persistence

I am making an iPad app where the user can create graphic content with images and text. I am storing this in memory in an array of custom UIView subclasses. Each of these view subclasses can have any number of subviews containing images or text.

Now I need to save these in the device. As I explore, there seem to be many ways to do this and would like to know what would be the best for this case.

Comment: There are many ways to do this, so it's hard to say what's "best."  Do you need to transmit this data to a server?  Also, you might take a look at UI state preservation--this is iOS's standard way of restoring state.  I'm not sure it will do what you want though.  There are many ways to do this, so it's hard to say what's "best."  Do you need to transmit this data to a server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are asking for the architectural design of what will end up being a Drawing app. This means that **best** it's really dependent on you specific use-cases, and cannot be answered completely unless you provide a quite detailed list of requirement.

But in general, I could try to give you some general tips that will have anyway to be integrated with you own specific nitty-gritty implementation.

This description will make some assumptions regarding the basic use cases that an app like this may need:

- The user can create an image using multiple tools to achieve the result. These can be anything, from a brush to a textfield and so on
- The information regarding *which* tools have been used to create the picture and *how* this tools have influenced the picture current look, can be saved in order to allow the user to later on edit the picture

Said this, the main problem is: *how to store your drawing state in order to recover it later*?

There are indeed many ways to achieve it, but I believe 2 of them are what would be considered "clean and famous enough".

### NSKeyedArchiver

This wouldn't be my favourite (difficult to maintain), but if you have to deal with UIView, it's probably gonna be the quickest. 
The [NSKeyedArchiver](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is

> .. a concrete subclass of NSCoder, provides a way to encode objects
>   (and scalar values) into an architecture-independent format that can
>   be stored in a file.

It implements the [Memento design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern) and It's the same pattern described in [Pro Objective-C Design Patterns](http://www.apress.com/9781430233305), that, incidentally, presents a case study that has many of the most important use-cases matching yours:

> - A drawing pad allows scribbling with the user’s finger.
>     [...]
> - It allows the user to save a scribble.
> - It allows the user to open a saved scribble.
>     [...]

It's an app for having a drawing pad, where you can draw lines with your finger.
Yours looks like a simplified version of this, with images and texts instead of the scribble.

So, what's the pro, in this specific case, of using the **NSKeyedArchiver**? The UIView already implements the [NSCoding protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/), the one needed to archive the object. So, for most of the information you need to store (coordinates, frame size, background color ...), you don't have to do anything but... archiving the object.

For any additional attribute on top of the UIView (for instance: the local path of your image, because [archiving an UIImageView is really expensive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513158/compressing-an-nskeyedarchiver-file-that-included-uiimageview-with-loaded-image)), you can take a look at [this article](http://nshipster.com/nscoding/) that explains with proper detail what you have to do in order to take advantage of the **NSKeyedArchiver** to store your object states.

This all boils down to:

1. implement the NSCoding protocol for each of the tools your drawing app is gonna provide
2. keep track of the subviews that the user create (images, text...)
3. when the user hit "save", loop through them, create an archive, and store them to a sensful path. The first component of the path could be the name of the Drawing, the second one the name of the tool and the third an id for each time the tool has been used. Like

   > ```
   > // A mountain image
   > /<path to you Document dir>/Mountains/Image/1
   >
   > // A sun
   > /<path to you Document dir>/Mountains/Image/2
   >
   > // The text "Mountain is awesome"
   > /<path to you Document dir>/Mountains/Text/1
   > ```
4. Then of course you will have to save the list of Drawing names somewhere, either in a plist file or in a **NSUserDefault**, so to be able to show them to the user in case they want to restore them for editing.

### Core data


This is probably the cleanest and more maintainable way to store you object states, but is gonna be a bit tough and cumbersome, in particular if it's the first time you use core data. I'm not gonna dig into Core Data, but I can give you some guidelines of the whole procedure. Basically:

1. You create a db schema that represents each of the **tools** your are gonna let the user use. Like: a table for *Image*, a table for *Text* and so on
2. On each table you put the attributes you need to remember (location, text color for "Text", image URL for "Image" and so on)
3. You create a table for the *Drawing* that the user create, with a 1-many relationship to the tool tables. This relations represents the object shown in the drawing.
4. Initialize you drawing canvas and each component according to what's stored in the db
5. Every time the user hit "save", create or update the proper db tables in order to reflect the current drawing configuration in the storage.

One of the advantages of this approach is that, if one day you want to change a tool component property or add new ones, you can take advantage of schema migrations in order to deliver backward compatibilities with new updates. So the users will still be able to use their old drawings.

### And so on and so forth...

These are two of the zilions of possibilities. You could use also use:

- **NSUSerDefault** to store states, that I suggest to avoid. It's gonna be really hard to maintain
- [Mix of the two aforementioned techniques](http://blog.artlogic.com/2013/05/28/persisting-view-controllers-with-core-data-objects/)
- If you plan to deliver >= iOS6 only support, you can check [this](http://blog.artlogic.com/2013/05/28/persisting-view-controllers-with-core-data-objects/)
- etc

The two I described are just what I feel are the usual and most discussed way of doing this. You find them in books, tutorials and they let you quite a lot of flexibility for anything you have to do.
If you need more explanatory links, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in a comment, you might want to look into iOS's state preservation API's.  However, if you want to build your own system to do this it'd be pretty simple using some clever categories and dictionaries.  Then you can serialize/deserialize your dictionaries using NSKeyedArchiver and NSKeyedUnarchiver.

eg:

```
@interface UIButton (MyAppCategory)

- (NSDictionary *)viewProperties;
- (void)configureFromProperties: (NSDictionary *) properties;

@end

@implementation UIButton (MyAppCategory)

- (NSDictionary *)viewProperties {
    return @{ @"class" : NSStringFromClass([self class]),
              @"frame" : [NSValue valueWithRect:self.frame],
              @"titleLabelText" : self.titleLabel.text,
              // etc...
            };
}

- (void)configureFromProperties: (NSDictionary *) properties {
    NSValue * value = properties[@"frame"];
    if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSValue class]]) {
        self.frame = value.rectValue;
    }
    NSSString * titleLabelText = properties[@"titleLabelText"];
    if ([titleLabelText isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        self.titleLabel.text = titleLabelText;
    }
}

@end

// replicate the above pattern for other view objects you need to support


@implementation MyViewFactory

- (UIView)recreateViewFromProperties: (NSDictionary *) properties {
    NSString * className = properties[@"class"];
    if ([className isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        Class viewClass = NSClassFromString(className);
        id viewObject = [[viewClass alloc] init];
        if ([viewObject respondsToSelector:@selector(configureFromProperties:)]]) {
            [viewObject performSelector:@selector(configureFromProperties:) withObject:properties];
            return viewObject;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

// exercise for the reader: iterate your views and use the viewProperties: method to collect your views' configuration info...

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow for future session editing and loading etc. I would suggest designing a data structure and create a core data model out of it.

Some structure holding the session metadata e.g. sessionID, creationDate, dictionary of key:imageName value:imageFrame (CGRect wrapped in NSValue, use setObjectForKey).

Loading images for the session would work by calling the keys into an array using e.g.[sessionImageDictionary allKeys], iterating through the keys and asynchronously (NSOperationQueue with `maxConcurrentOperationCount`) loading the image at some Macro path to e.g. the library directory, and appending the key, which is the imageName.

In the same iteration you can set its frame by calling `[sessionImageDictionary valueForKey:[arrayOfKeys objectAtIndex:currentIteration];` Converting the previously stored NSValue back to CGRect.

The datastructure all depends on the amount of features you want, but the good thing is it allows for expansion and with core data as the backing store, you could do things like sync between devices, enable multiple sessions for loading and saving like a "My projects" feature. It will help if lets say the user builds up a library of images (all stored in your apps library directory) and then the user uses the same image in the same session or in multiple sessions, only one copy of the image needs to exist, with zero duplicate write outs to disk and the core data object will have the filename stored in the session.

The most important part would be building a correct Core-Data model and writing an extractor that can accept these custom subclasses, strip out the data to create, populate and save an NSManagedObject to the persistent store.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to use `UIDocument` with `NSFileWrapper` folder. Then you can store all your files in one folder which is saved automatically when the contents change.
Refer to:http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocumentBasedAppPGiOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011149-CH1-SW1